# What are the "string", "stream" and "stringstream" classes in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to know what's the difference between string and stream in c++, and what's stringstream?

Answer (score 9):

Very Informally: A string is a collection of characters, a stream is a tool to manipulate moving data around. A string stream is a c++ class that lets you use a string as the source and destination of data for a stream.

Answer (score 8):

- `istream` and `ostream`: interfaces to streaming data (files, sockets, etc.)
- [`istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/istringstream.html): an `istream` that wraps a string and offers its contents
- [`ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/ostringstream.html): an `ostream` that saves the content written to it as a string

Example:

```
istringstream datastream("1 2 3");

int val;
datastream >> val;
cout << val << endl; // prints 1

datastream >> val;
cout << val << endl; // prints 2

datastream >> val;
cout << val << endl; // prints 3


ostringstream outstream;
outstream << 1 << "+" << 2 << "=" << 3;
cout << outstream.str() << endl; // prints "1+2=3"
```

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that a stringstream is like an iostream, but instead of writing to or reading from a file, you write to or read from a string.

Answer (score 2):

In C and/or Unix, the basic metaphor was the file. Standard out, standard in, network sockets were all represented using file descriptors. Thus you can use `fprintf()` to write into these "files" without knowing what's really underneath.

As a safer and cooler alternative, C++ presented [iostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/) as the basic metaphor which is almost built into the language using `<<` operator. Again, files, strings and (with library) network can be accessed using streams without knowing what it is.