# Why doesn't getline(ss, tmp, ' ') read a line of input without white space at the end?

Tags: c++

Here's my code:

```
string input;
getline(cin, input, ' ');
cout << input;
```

If input is "abc", nothing gets printed.
It only works if there's whitespace at the end of input, such as "abc ".

Update:
I understand that I've specified ' ' as the delimiter, so getline() would stop at ' '. But I expect getline() to stop at the end of input, even though it does not encounter a space.

In addition, if I do this

```
string input;
getline(cin, input);
stringstream ss(input);
getline(ss, input, ' ');
cout << input;
```

my input gets printed out with no problem.
What confuses me is that `cin` stream in the first version and `ss` stream in the second seem to have the same content("abc"), but only the second one works. It seems to me that in the second version at line 4, `getline()` stops at end of stream, while in the first version it does not.

The second version has redundant operations. I only made it up to better explain my question.

Comment: What do you know about that third parameter `' '` that you are passing to getline?

Comment: Please take some time to read e.g. [this `std::getline` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). It basically reads until the end of the input, or the delimiter is found.

Comment: If you want to read whole lines and then extract space-delimited "words", I recommend you use `std::getline` to read *without* delimiter, to get whole line. Then in a loop use a `std::istringstream` to extract "words" using the plain stream extraction operator `>>`.

Comment: Please do not tag spam. Adding tags that do not apply to your post is not appropriate. Please read the tag descriptions before using them, and use only those that are applicable to your question. I've removed the *basic* tag. Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: i dont think you need to pass in a `' '` in the parameter. i never used the third parameter in getline and it always worked for me

Comment: The third parameter specifies what the "newline" characters is supposed to be. The code says it is space, and not the `'\n'` it would be otherwise. So it reads "space delimited lines".

Comment: @BoP *So it read "space deimited words"* -- but we know what you meant `:)`

Answer (score -1):

As many people pointed out that getline reads until the end of input or if a delimiter is found, you're specifically putting a delimiter on the getline. This is what you're doing:

**Your Code**

```
    string input;
    getline(cin, input, ' ');
    cout << input;
```

when you said you don't want the getline to have a space at the end to read it.
I think you were supposed to just do this much:

```
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << input;
```

in this code, the getline only reads the input and since there aren't any delimiters given, it wont wait for any delimiter(or a space as you've written in your code) for it to read the string.

tell me if it works or not

Comment: If you don't specify the third parameter, it defaults to `'\n'` and getline still waits for the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your fix works. However, I still don't understand why my code doesn't work. I've added more explanation to my post if you could take a look.

Comment: @ClumsyHat - Please provide [A Minimal Complete Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. If the `' '` delimiter is causing problems it is likely due to the state of your input stream before you make your `getline()` call. If this is your 1st or only input in your program, you are right -- there is no reason what you have shouldn't work - to read from `stdin` up to the first space character.

Comment: @ClumsyHat - I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312245/what-are-the-string-stream-and-stringstream-classes-in-c#:~:text=Very%20Informally%3A%20A%20string%20is,of%20data%20for%20a%20stream.&text=istream%20and%20ostream%20%3A%20interfaces%20to,files%2C%20sockets%2C%20etc.) one works for you.